# An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile

Tags: flutter, ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Tengo problemas con mi app en iOS, estoy trabajando con Flutter 2.2.2 pero al momento de ejecutarla me sale este error `Consistency issue: build setting` IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`has multiple values:`{"Release"=>"14.0", "Debug"=>"8.0", "Profile"=>"8.0"}``
En XCode modifiqué mi deployment target a iOS 14.0 en Release, Debug y Profile pero aún así me sale el mismo error, también modifiqué mi podfile, descomentando la linea principal del target ios a 14.0, hay algo que me falte modificar porque no encuentro solución en ninguna parte. Si sirve de algo estoy utilizando pod en la versión 1.11.3

**Este es mi podfile modificado**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '14.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'Branch'
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET']='14.0'
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    end
  end
end
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 2.6.4', '< 4.0'
end
```

Comment: Estas en SO en español quizas quieras ir a [SO] o traducir la pregunta

Comment: Lo siento no me di cuenta, ya hice la consulta en español @Excorpion

Comment: Si modificaste el archivo `.podfile` ejecutaste `pod update`?

Comment: @Bicho, si hice todo eso pero ni así funciona